# how to update multiple data using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am a newbie in here and i have a problem that me myself cannot find the exact solution... here it is... i need to build a system that will update all the staff information. through this system, a staff in human resource department will enter all the staffs information. i have been create this code to update the staffs information but it seems not function with what i really want.... i just want to update by rows however, it turns to update all rows in the database...

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("includes/database.php");
include ("includes/security.php");
include ("includes/config.php");

$nama=$_SESSION["nama"];
$pwd=$_SESSION["status"];

$nama=$_POST["st_nama"];
$siri1=$_POST["st_siri"];
$siri2=$_POST["st_siri2"];
$siri3=$_POST["st_siri3"];
$jawatan=$_POST["st_jawatan"];
$gred=$_POST["st_gred"];
$gredh=$_POST["st_gredh"];
$gelaran=$_POST["st_gelaran"];
$elaun=$_POST["st_elaun"];
$id=$_GET["id"];

$dataPengguna2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_rekod where id='$id'");


mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_rekod set st_nama='$nama', st_siri='$siri1', st_siri2='$siri2', st_siri3='$siri3', st_jawatan='$jawatan', st_gred='$gred', st_gredh='$gredh', st_gelaran='$gelaran', st_elaun='$elaun' WHERE id='$id'") or die (mysql_error());

$status = "REKOD BERJAYA DIKEMASKINI!<br/><a href = 'stafflogin.php'><strong>KEMBALI KE LAMAN UTAMA</strong></a>";



?>
```

Comment: I hope you don't use this in production. All that sql vulnerability.

Comment: What exactly does `include ("includes/security.php");` do? Cause I'm not seeing it.

Comment: it is to make sure that the right person can enter the system... from the login page

Comment: It means that you leave yourself open to someone sabotaging your database or worse.

Comment: In regards to your question, is the `id` field unique and always filled with a value?

Comment: @Rasclatt i am not really understand the way to develop all the system things.. but i just know the basic to crate the forms, without any instruction.. it is my bad... as for the id,yes, it is always filled with a value...

Comment: Is it always unique?

Comment: The vulnerability @Darren is talking about is called sql injection. Example: someone puts sql code in the form and you allow your database to run their code since you didn't check the contents of $_POST. Google sql injection to learn more - it can cause very bad things.

Answer (score 0):

This will help fix your sql injection issue, and may also fix update 1 vs multiple rows issue. This method uses the `PDO` library in PHP. You can see more info on using `PDO` on the PHP site. It replaces the `mysql_` set of commands which are no longer included in the PHP releases.

```
// Below replaces the mysql_connect() so it requires db credentials filled in
try {
        $host   =   'hostname';
        $db     =   'databasename';
        $user   =   'username';
        $pass   =   'password';
        $con    =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
    }
// This replaces the die("error message") potion of a mysql_connect() set-up
catch (Exception $e) {
      $_errors['connect']['message']    =   $e->getMessage();
      $_errors['connect']['error_code'] =   $e->getCode();
    }

$nama       =   $_SESSION["nama"];
$pwd        =   $_SESSION["status"];

$nama       =   $_POST["st_nama"];
$siri1      =   $_POST["st_siri"];
$siri2      =   $_POST["st_siri2"];
$siri3      =   $_POST["st_siri3"];
$jawatan    =   $_POST["st_jawatan"];
$gred       =   $_POST["st_gred"];
$gredh      =   $_POST["st_gredh"];
$gelaran    =   $_POST["st_gelaran"];
$elaun      =   $_POST["st_elaun"];
$id         =   $_GET["id"];

// You should do just a preliminary check that the id is a numeric value
// No sense in continuing if someone tries to foil the natural
// order of your code
if(is_numeric($id)) {
        // The next 3 lines would be equivalent to the mysql_query("statement here")
        // as well as a more robust version of mysql_real_escape_string(). It does more,
        // but for sake of explanation it does that and more.
        $dataPengguna2  =   $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_rekod where id=:id");
        // Binding paramaters basically sanitizes the value being inserted into your query
        $dataPengguna2->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $dataPengguna2->execute();

        // There is no indication of what you are doing with the select above

        // Set up the update statement
        $query  =   $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_rekod set st_nama=:st_nama, st_siri=:st_siri, st_siri2=:st_siri2, st_siri3=:st_siri3, st_jawatan=:st_jawatan, st_gred=:st_gred, st_gredh=:st_gredh, st_gelaran=:st_gelaran, st_elaun=:st_elaun WHERE id=:id");
        // Bind all the values to sanitize against injection
        // You could do a function that loops through an array of values,
        // but this is one way to do it manually
        $query->bindParam(':st_nama',$nama);
        $query->bindParam(':st_siri',$siri1);
        $query->bindParam(':st_siri2',$siri2);
        $query->bindParam(':st_siri3',$siri3);
        $query->bindParam(':st_jawatan',$jawatan);
        $query->bindParam(':st_gred',$gred);
        $query->bindParam(':st_gredh',$gredh);
        $query->bindParam(':st_gelaran',$gelaran);
        $query->bindParam(':st_elaun',$elaun);
        $query->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $query->execute();

        // Print out error info. There may be something of value here
        // that may help you figure out why it's trying to update all your rows
        // instead of just the one.
        print_r($query->errorInfo());

        $status = "REKOD BERJAYA DIKEMASKINI!<br/><a href = 'stafflogin.php'><strong>KEMBALI KE LAMAN UTAMA</strong></a>";
    } ?>
```